# Write bit value to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, boolean, bit

I'm trying to write a bit value (true or false) into my database in a field called "processed". i'm currently trying to do this by passing in bool values, but I get an error saying can't convert from type varchar to bit. Can anybody see what is going on in my logic?

```
       protected void CheckBoxProcess_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool update;
        bool trueBool = true;
        bool falseBool = false;
        string checkedString = "UPDATE SecureOrders SET processed = '%" + trueBool + "%' WHERE fName LIKE '%" + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "%' AND lName LIKE '% " + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text + "%'";
        string uncheckedString = "UPDATE SecureOrders SET processed = '%" + falseBool + "%' WHERE fName LIKE '%" + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "%' AND lName LIKE '% " + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text + "%'";
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)cb.Parent.Parent;
        DefaultGrid.SelectedIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
        update = Convert.ToBoolean(DefaultGrid.SelectedValue);

        orderByString = orderByList.SelectedItem.Value;
        fieldString = searchTextBox.Text;


        System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connectionString;

        connectionString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["secureodb"];



        // Create an SqlConnection to the database.
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand checkedCmd = new SqlCommand(checkedString, connection);
            SqlCommand uncheckedCmd = new SqlCommand(uncheckedString, connection);
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SecureOrders", connection);

            // create the DataSet
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            // fill the DataSet using our DataAdapter               
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "SecureOrders");

            DataView source = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
            DefaultGrid.DataSource = source;


            if (cb.Checked == true)
            {
                checkedCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            else
            {
                uncheckedCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }






    }
```

Comment: why don't u keep `int` and `0` `1` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the bit fields to `1` or `0` depending on whether it is true or false.

So:

```
string checkedString = "UPDATE SecureOrders SET processed = 1 WHERE fName LIKE '%" + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "%' AND lName LIKE '% " + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text + "%'";
string uncheckedString = "UPDATE SecureOrders SET processed = 0 WHERE fName LIKE '%" + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "%' AND lName LIKE '% " + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text + "%'";
```

Also, as has been mentioned in the comments, constructing your SQL statements directly from user input is the easiest way to fall victim to SQL Injection attacks.  It's always best to use paramaterized queries (or even Stored Procs) in those cases.

```
....
string checkedString = "UPDATE SecureOrders SET processed = 1 WHERE fName LIKE @p1 AND lName LIKE @p2";
string uncheckedString = "UPDATE SecureOrders SET processed = 0 WHERE fName LIKE @p1 AND lName LIKE @p2";
```

You can then create parameters to pass to your `ExecuteNonQuery` call

```
SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@p1",SqlDbType.Varchar) { Value = string.Format("%{0}%",DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text) };
SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@p2",SqlDbType.Varchar) { Value = string.Format("%{0}%",DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text) };
if (cb.Checked == true)
{
    checkedCmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
    checkedCmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
    checkedCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
else
{
    uncheckedCmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
    uncheckedCmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
    uncheckedCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. This is what I had before, but my problem now is that it's not actually writing anything to the database...I'm assuming more code would need to be seen?

Comment: One issue (I think) is that your filling your DataAdapter before your doing your update...so any changes made by the update will not be reflected by the results in the DataGrid.

Comment: Am I crazy or is everyone ignoring the fact that this way of constructing SQL statements is a classic example of SQL injection vulnerability?  Not only that, but if he fixed that problem he would also fix the problem this question is about...?

Comment: Yeah, and I always have to debate with myself whether to mention such things in the answers. Since technically the question is about a specific issue, rather than "what is wrong with this", I opted to ignore it in this case.

Comment: I hear you.  If you edit your answer to mention the vulnerability I can remove the -1 (it's locked at this point).

Comment: You convinced me :)  Less for the upvote, and more for the guilt of letting unchecked inputs through.

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that you will solve your problem if you inject into your SQL statement string "1" for True and "0" for False, the "proper" way to solve this problem is to parameterize your SQL statement and add parameters to the command object.  Type conversion from a VB `Boolean` to `SqlDbType.Bit` is then done by the framework.

Try:

```
string sqlString = "UPDATE SecureOrders SET processed = @Processed WHERE fName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' AND lName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'";
```

And:

```
        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, connection);
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Processed", cb.Checked);
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text);
```

Finally:

```
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you are going to be writing data-driven web applications it's very important you understand how to avoid the SQL injection security vulnerability.  For more information: [MSDN How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL a bit value is either 1 or 0, not 'true' or 'false'. Change the 'true' and 'false' to 1 and 0 in your update and you should be OK. (Note the 0 and 1 don't have quotes either.)

Comment: Hm, I did this, but it wasn't working before. I guess I can try it again.

Comment: It should work, ensure you don't have quotes around the number.

Comment: The problem is that it's not actually writing anything to the database :/ The 1 and 0 are registering as bit values fine I guess, but it won't write out.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is wrong - you're passing a string as the value to set the `processed` columns value as, which you can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to Convert.ToInt16 your Boolean value.  That will make true/false, 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean values are being concatenated as "true"|"false".  Try using a ternary operator to display either "1" or "0":

```
string checkedString = "UPDATE SecureOrders SET processed = '%" + (trueBool ? "1" : "0") + "%' WHERE fName LIKE '%" + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text + "%' AND lName LIKE '% " + DefaultGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is not trying to set any sort of boolean, it's trying to set the text `%True%` or `%False%`.

Since you described the database field as a "bit" rather than as a "boolean", you'll probably need to use something like `"processed = " + (trueBool ? 1 : 0) + "` when constructing your string. But depending on the SQL server you are using, you may be able to get away with something like `processed = " + trueBool + "` or `processed = '" + trueBool + "'`.

Or, in this particular case, you can skip interpolating `trueBool` and just use an entirely-constant string as most of the other answers have suggested.

Also, BTW, note that you are leaving yourself wide open for errors and SQL injection by interpolating unchecked user input into your SQL statements. For example, if someone enters "O'Brian" as the last name you will get errors, and with more malicious choices of values they may be able to alter anything in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Very old qestion but I hope this could help someone.

To write a bit value to an sql Database from codebehind C# follow this example.

1.- First declare a variable to get the value 0 or 1 (in this case it's depending the Checkbox1 status):

```
int isenable = 0;
            if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                enable = 1;
            }
```

2.- Then create your connection, your sql query and execute it:

```
string connetionString1 = null;
            SqlConnection connection1;
            connetionString1 = "Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=Scrapper;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myUser;Password=Mypassword123";
            connection1 = new SqlConnection(connetionString1);
            connection1.Open();
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO usuarios(numgaffete, windowsid, name, enable, email) VALUES ('" + txtgafete.Text + "', '" + txtwindowsid.Text + "', '" + txtname.Text + "', '" + Convert.ToInt16(isenable) + "', '" + Email.Text + "')",
                connection1);
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note your int variable (isenable) must be converted to int 16 in the SQL INSERT command in order to avoid errors when the command is executed.